# How to create an AWS Inline Policy that can create and read specific secret?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

I want to create a role with a policy that is able to only create a specific resource (secret in secrets manager) named "secret_x" and only able to read this resource.

The following policy does not work when trying to create the secret, giving the error: "no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:CreateSecret action":

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCreateAndReadSecret",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:CreateSecret",
                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:<account_nr>:secret:secret_x"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The AWS standard SecretManagerReadWrite policy contains many other services, I can't find (except for KMS) why these are required:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "BasePermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:*",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                "docdb-elastic:GetCluster",
                "docdb-elastic:ListClusters",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "kms:ListKeys",
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusters",
                "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
                "redshift:DescribeClusters",
                "redshift-serverless:ListWorkgroups",
                "redshift-serverless:GetNamespace",
                "tag:GetResources"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "LambdaPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:AddPermission",
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:SecretsManager*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SARPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "serverlessrepo:CreateCloudFormationChangeSet",
                "serverlessrepo:GetApplication"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:serverlessrepo:*:*:applications/SecretsManager*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::awsserverlessrepo-changesets*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::secrets-manager-rotation-apps-*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I make the principle in such way that it can only create and only read the secret_x while at the same time having as less permissions as possible?